# Excel to pdf not all content can be seen

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, pdf

I have a excel which is save in pdf format.
In the pdf one of my content does not reflect how it is suppose to look like in excel.
I have use auto fit and that is the result it shows.
When I manually adjust the cell height, then I am able to see the content in pdf format.
Is there a easier way to solve this problem other than using manual adjusting?

Excel: [image: How it look like in excel]

pdf: [image: how it looks like in pdf format]

Comment: Can you add some images of your excel and pdf files so that it would be more clear to understand and answer..

Comment: Excel is known to have issues with table formatting.  Ultimate solution would be to export your table to PDF from Word.

Comment: it seems you've posted the same picture twice:(

Comment: Is the cell in Excel merged?

Comment: No, the cell is not merged